# What determines the size and shape of a cell?

Tags: anatomy, cell

What determines the size and shape of a cell? They differ at different tissues / organs/ species

Comment: Can you add some specifics to your question? Have you done any previous research, and are you particularly interested in a certain type of cells (eg bacteria, plant, animal tissue etc)?

Comment: Can confirm, this is the exact question that motivates my research interests, and I can tell you that even now this is far from a settled question, in pretty much any organism.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite a hard to answer question.
There are different cell cycle molecules that, if mutated or knocked out, have shown to cause the cell to have a different shape or "overgrow" in size or not grow at all...

You might find some insight [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15589139?dopt=AbstractPlus).

There are lots of factors that influence cell size and shape, thus it is a very complex system to study. For example, cell shape is influenced by the cytoskeleton but also other factors.